# Old VS code not running with new VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have an old project that I need to revisit. It was built in some version of Visual C++ (prolly 2005) looking at the .sln file. The sln file wont get converted to a VS 2008 solution due to some corruption (dubug point -1). I imported the folder in VS as a new project and tried compiling.

It gave compilation errors for `"lang/Typedefs.h/Assertions.h"` not there. Removing the declarations I had errors for Uint8/16/32/64 not declared. So I added the typedefs and other macros `(TOOLS_UNUSED_PARAMETERS(x) / TOOLS_FORBID_COPY())`.

That being ironed out, I got errors for Gui/FileDlg.h and Gui/FolderDlg.h(debug point - 2).

I didnt find any of those header files from any resources online or in my current VS installation and so I am assuming that code is missing and I will have to redo it.

Even these could probably have been custom implemented by the earlier programmer. The current MFC uses `CFileDialog` and the code uses  `Gui::FileDlg`.

I commented out the code for the time being to see where can I get to since gui is not that big a part of the application. Later I see linker errors corresponding to RegKeyOpenEx calls and outputstream calls(dubug point -3). Winreg.h was not included but windows.h was.

sample :

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxA@16 
referenced in function "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall FileManager::getOutputStream(class Interface   
*,class LogPoint *)" (?getOutputStream@FileManager@@QAEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?
$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAVInterface@@PAVLogPoint@@@Z)    filemanager.obj 
PCAPGenerator
```

I am not a .Net programmer so can you please suggest what would be the right course of action here ?
which debug points should i be focussing on.

Comment: This does not sound like .net code, so not being a .net programmer doesn't factor into it.

Comment: im not well versed with visual studio in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegKeyOpenEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a Winapi function defined in `Advapi32.dll`. To link that into a Visual C++ project:

- If your project is a static library (right-click project->`Properties->Configuration Properties->Configuration Type->Static Library (.lib)`, go to `Configuration Properties->Librarian->General->Additional Dependencies` and add `Advapi32.lib`.
- If your project is a dll (same place, says `Dynamic Library (.dll)` instead), you'll have the `Linker` section instead of `Librarian`. Go to its `Input` subsection, and add `Advapi32.lib` to `Additional Dependencies`.

For your remaining linker errors, proceed in the same way: go to the MSDN doc for the function, check which dll/lib it belongs to and have your project link it in as described above.

Comment: I added Winreg.h for that and that went away .. I am not sure about the Linker error :
Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxA@16 referenced in function "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall FileManager::getOutputStream(class Interface *,class LogPoint *)" (?getOutputStream@FileManager@@QAEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAVInterface@@PAVLogPoint@@@Z) filemanager.obj PCAPGenerator

Comment: Same idea; MessageBoxA is a variant of the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) function, which is defined in User32.lib. Link that into your project.